# Excel 'put random value in a cell and run permutation " easiest problem

Tags: excel, excel-formula, permutation, excel-tables

I have an Easy problem. Anyone kindly assist.

I have name(s) in Excel I would like to populate with a random full stop in between the name

For instance

```
   A.    B. 
 1 Name  n.ame
 2       n.a.me
 3.      n.a.m.e
 4.      na.me
```

Etc all possible names to be listed. I'm so terrible in Excel but I'm definitely traveling back to the basics.

Comment: what version of Excel are you using ?

Comment: Hey Gary, I'm using Excel version 2013.

Comment: Not really permutations that you are talking about, more like subsets of the set of spaces between characters. If `n` is the length of the name then there would be `2^(n-1)-1` patterns of the sort you are talking about. Trivial with VBA but difficult with just formulas (and probably impossible without a fixed length or at least upper bound on the lengths of the names).

Comment: Even though I understand why the question has been closed (and in fact came close to voting to close it earlier), it has attracted some high-quality answers that might be useful to others, For that reason I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

### Randomly Insert Character Into String

Keeping in mind that this is a pseudo random generator try this for a string in `A1`:

```
=REPLACE(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,LEN(A1)+1),0,".")
```

Additionally you can improve:

```
=IF(A1="","",REPLACE(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,LEN(A1)+1),0,"."))
```

or even:

```
=IF(NOT(ISTEXT(A1)),"",REPLACE(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,LEN(A1)+1),0,"."))
```

Comment: I did not realize that you can insert characters with `REPLACE()`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Neither did I, but I tried and 'conquered'. But the answer is totally wrong. I got mislead by the random part.

Comment: I think your answer is great way to randomly place a single dot.

Comment: @Jamie: If you don't want the dot on the last position, remove '+1' from the formula, if you don't want the last two dots, replace '+1' with '-1' etc..Similarly, if you don't want the dot before, you increase the first argument ('lower bound'?) of RANDBETWEEN by one.

Comment: What if A1 was name@mail

Answer (score 1):

If you had Excel 2019 you could use textjoin and do something like this:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("",1,IF(ISODD(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))),MID($A$1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))+1)/2,1),
IF(MID(DEC2BIN(ROW(),LEN($A$1)-1),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))/2,1)="1",".",""))),"")
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

[image]

What I suggest is that you find one of the implementations of textjoin or concat for earlier versions of Excel that are available e.g. [the one here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/text-join-formula-for-excel-2010.1044904/) . The above formula could be modified to use this instead:

```
=IFERROR(cat(IF(ISODD(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))),MID($A$1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))+1)/2,1),IF(MID(DEC2BIN(ROW(),LEN($A$1)-1),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))/2,1)="1",".","")),"",1),"")
```

**EDIT**

In light of @John Coleman's helpful comment, an improved version of the first formula above would use Base(number,2,min_length) instead of dec2bin which can only handle values up to 511 or 2^9-1 (putting a ceiling of 10 characters on the name):

```
=IF(ROW()<2^(LEN($A$1)-1),TEXTJOIN("",1,IF(ISODD(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))),MID($A$1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))+1)/2,1),
IF(MID(BASE(ROW(),2,LEN($A$1)-1),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)*2-1))/2,1)="1",".",""))),"")
```

Comment: I'm impressed (+1). I didn't think it was possible in a humanly-readable way using just spreadsheet formulas. Unfortunately OP is using Excel 2013 and the question has since been closed.

Comment: But wouldn't `Base(_,2)` be better than `DEC2BIN`? That legacy function is so restricted that many perfectly realistic names would crash with it.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up - I was using Excel 2010 until recently and wasn't aware of the Base function.